# HTML Menu Runs Off Screen

Tags: html, css

I have a menu at the top of my screen with my pages, but it runs off of the left side of the screen by quite a few pixels. I am running my site off of a 10 grid (10 grid parts, 10% wide on each), but it is going way past 100%.

CSS:

```
ul {
    background: #000000;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul li {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    color: #0f7e25;
}

ul li a {
    color: #0f7e25;
}

ul li a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header>
    <ul class="grid_10">
        <li><a href="#">Front Door Web Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Let's Talk</a></li>
    </ul>
```

JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/P3F3Y/

Comment: Can you provide an example on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: With the code you've provided, it works well, so we cannot reproduce the same thing with the code provided as it's not sufficient to solve the issue, either share a demo on jsfiddle, or share more code

Comment: Tried with the code you provided (with some little fix): http://jsfiddle.net/Y47U2/

Comment: If you have 10% sets width of elements. All padding and margin is extra. So if you have 10 elements 10% wide and every element have some padding and margin, than the total space for all the elements will be grater than 10%

Comment: @user2915402 overflow hidden is not a solution for menu, because you would want to see all your menu items :D

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/P3F3Y/

Comment: It looks a little off with JSFiddle but I hope it works.

Comment: @Skriptotajs If you remove it, the menu will collapse because of floats, it's an alternative to the classic clearfix. Also, if the menu is wider than the viewport it will break the layout (topic of this question).

Answer (score 0):

Padding is expanding the list beyond the width of the page. You need to reduce the padding on li

```
ul li {
   padding-right:20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    color: #0f7e25;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ankur1990/ab3pF/